# How to translate this mysql query to a Django query?

Tags: mysql, django

How to translate to a Django query?

```
select distinct(p.recipe_id) from photos p where p.photo_order in (select pp.photo_order from photos pp where pp.photo_order = p.photo_order and p.id != pp.id) group by p.recipe_id, p.photo_order having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Too much SQL there to work it out. Instead, say in words exactly what result you are hoping to get.

Answer (score 0):

You could read this part of the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) and figure it out yourself. Either that or give us more information about your models and what you need to get.